# Understanding the example from MILC framework - python decorator main call

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Hello World implementation using MILC.
"""

from milc import cli

@cli.entrypoint('Greet a user.')
def main(cli):
   cli.log.info('Hello, World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   cli()
```

MILC is a framework for writing CLI applications in Python.
In the example provided after calling the file there is a "Hello World" in the console output.
I don't understand who is calling the **main**() function.
Any light on this?

Comment: Presumably somewhere inside `cli()`

Comment: This won't help you directly. 1st check how python will figure out if your script is called directly or from another script. This may help you - [__main__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) . 2nd - frameworks usually expect from you to write code that the framework will execute. Here you have [decorator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0318/) "*cli.entrypoint*" - I think this is convention of the framework. It will execute the method with this decorator. Maybe ... I don't know this framework though